# Can github-copilot create new classes for suggestions with the Intellij Plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, github-copilot

If I create an Entity class in Intellij, and then, in that file,  "ask" co-pilot for a repostiory
Like this:

`//create Repository for Book entity class`
It comes up with this perfectly valid solution for a name and location(but not more)

`// Path: src\main\java\dat3.library.repository\BookRepository.java`

If I now open the Copilot window and press the Refresh button it comes up with a completely acceptable suggestion, extending the JpaRepository.
But when I press the "accept the  solution" button, it inserts the repository inside the Entity class file, even if the suggestion includes the correct repository package.

Am I missing something, or can Github Copilot/the Intellij-plugin really only create hints inside a single file?
If it can, any suggestion to how, will be much appreciated.